# Own office DNS server on Ubuntu 11.4-server

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, ubuntu-11.04

Can anyone help me (I'm stuck) with configuring DNS server?

**Description:**

We have one Ubuntu 11.4-server machine and 3 Ubuntu 11.4-secktop.

Local IP addresses:

- Ubuntu 11.4-server:  192.168.1.3
- tolik (Ubuntu 11.4): 192.168.1.7
- yura  (Ubuntu 11.4): 192.168.1.77
- artur (Ubuntu 11.4): 192.168.1.12

**Goal:**

Setup DNS server that any machine in our LAN can access http server on 192.168.1.3 via http://intell-sd.com

Atm we have bind 9 installed and this config:

**/etc/bind/named.conf.local**

```
zone "intell-sd.com" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/intell-sd.com.db";
};

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/rev.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
};
```

**/etc/bind/named.conf.options**

```
options {
    forwarders {
        213.130.16.20; #our provider DNS
    }
};
```

**/etc/resolv.conf**

```
search intell-sd.com.
nameserver 192.168.1.3
```

**/etc/bind/zones/intell-sd.com.db**

```
$TTL 3D
@ IN SOA ns.intell-sd.com. admin.intell-sd.com. (
    2007062001
    28800
    3600
    604800
    38400
);
intell-sd.com.  IN   NS        ns.intell-sd.com.
tolik           IN   A         192.168.1.7
artur           IN   A         192.168.1.77
yura            IN   A         192.168.1.12
WWW             IN   CNAME     artur
gw              IN   A         192.168.1.1
                     TXT       "Network Gateway"
```

**/etc/bind/zones/rev.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa**

```
$TTL 3D
@ IN SOA ns.intell-sd.com. admin.intell-sd.com. (
     2007062001
     28800
     604800
     604800
     86400
)
        IN      NS      ns.intell-sd.com.
1       IN      PTR     gw.intell-sd.com.
10      IN      PTR     tolik.intell-sd.com.
11      IN      PTR     yura.intell-sd.com.
12      IN      PTR     artur.intell-sd.com.
```

But nothing work (intell-sd.com return "aborted" status).

**Debug:**

**BIND starts without any fails.**

**dig intell-sd.com (from 192.168.1.12):**

```
global options: +cmd
Got answer:
->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 4434
flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

QUESTION SECTION:
intell-sd.com.          IN  A

Query time: 0 msec
SERVER: 192.168.1.3#53(192.168.1.3)
WHEN: Thu Aug 25 16:02:02 2011
MSG SIZE  rcvd: 31
```

**nslookup gw**

```
Server:     192.168.1.3
Address:    192.168.1.3#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find gw: No answer
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a wildcard record for this.

Add the following to your intell-sd.com zone:

```
*      IN CNAME    WWW.intell-sd.com.
```

Also, you should change your WWW CNAME to point to the FQDN of artur:

```
WWW    IN CNAME    artur.intell-sd.com.
```

Comment: changed /etc/bind/zones/intell-sd.com.db but nothing happened

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer (+1)! But I reconfigured bind9 in some another way.

Answer (score 3):

There is no A record in the zone for intell-sd.com., which is your query in the dig output above. You could add it in the zone as follows to achieve your goal:

```
@           IN   A         192.168.1.3
```

Comment: add your line to /etc/bind/zones/intell-sd.com.db but nothing happened

Comment: did you update the serial number in the zone and reload it?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer (+1)! But I reconfigured bind9 in some another way.